# how to use use transparent proxy(local host) in middle of browser and destination server?

Tags: c#

" we ask the browser to send all the traffic to localhost and then the traffic can be sent to our server

otherwise browser will make requests directly towards the destination server(e.g. google ).."

Transparent proxy can be used in any place it does not break the http and https traffic.

```
Browser -> lcoal host(create ssl) -> our server -> google
```

so, how to use use transparent the proxy(local host) in  the middle of browser and destination server??

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)'s quickstart videos.  This is a tool used as a proxy for web debugging, and is used as a transparent proxy as you describe.  The basic idea is the same, you have to configure your browser to point at the proxy and then the proxy has to 'forward' the traffic on.

Comment: you want to do what with C#? I'm now confused.  Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve? It might be easier to suggest something.